# How to iterate a list of objects in jstl inside jsp

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I am trying to iterate a list of objects in my jsp using jstl. I want that for each param name, a dropdown containing the param values appear.

jsp code:

```
<c:if test="${fn:length(listOfParams) gt 0}">
    <h2>Yo YO</h2>
    <c:forEach var="param" items="${listOfParams}">
        <h3>${param.paramName}</h3>
        <select name="${param.paramName}" id="${param.paramName}"
            class="target">
            <c:forEach var="listOfParamValue" items="${param.listOfParamValue}">
                <option><c:out value="${listOfParamValue}" /></option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
    </c:forEach>
</c:if>
```

Controller Code:

```
    DTEJob dteJob2 = new DTEJob();
    dteJob2.setParamName("ABC");
    dteJob2.addTolistOfParamValue("val1");
    dteJob2.addTolistOfParamValue("val2");
    dteJob2.setDefault(true);
    paramList.add(dteJob2);
    model.addAttribute("listOfParams", paramList);
```

OUTPUT:

Yo YO  and 2 empty drop downs.

Can anyone help why I am unable to retrieve the values in jstl? Any help will be appreciated as I am new to jsp and jstl.

My bean class is:

```
private String paramName;
private List<String> listOfParamValue=new ArrayList<String>();

public List<String> getListOfParamValue() {
    return listOfParamValue;
}

public String getParamName() {
    return paramName;
}
```

Comment: Can you please be more clear . Are you passing list of list from your model ? show your bean ?

Comment: Yes, its list of list. I have added the bean class in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `var="param"` to `var="p"` or anything other than `param` because `param` is used to access request parameter.

```
<c:forEach var="p" items="${listOfParams}">
```

---

`${param.paramName}` means access `paramName` as request parameter that is not there.

Read more about [JSP - Implicit Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnahq.html#bnaij)

> `param:` Maps a request parameter name to a single value

Comment: welcome. Is your [next question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25076794/issue-in-getting-attribute-value-from-model-object-in-get-request-in-spring-mvc) still valid? if yes then update it, I'll reopen it.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this ,

```
<c:if test="${not empty listOfParams}">
    <h2>Yo YO</h2>
    <c:forEach var="param" items="${listOfParams}">
        <h3>${param.paramName}</h3>
        <select name="${param.paramName}" id="${param.paramName}"
            class="target">
            <c:forEach var="temp" items="${2nd list name here}">
                <option><c:out value="${temp.listOfParamValue}"></c:out></option>
            </c:forEach>
        </select>
    </c:forEach>
</c:if>
```

The list inside `items` attribute is independent

Comment: I tried this but it didn't worked:
`<c:if test="${fn:length(listOfParams) gt 0}">
  <h2>Yo YO</h2>
  <c:forEach var="param" items="${listOfParams}">
  <c:out value="${param.paramName}" />
   <h3>${param.paramName}</h3>
   <select name="${param.paramName}" id="${param.paramName}"
    class="target">
    <c:forEach var="temp" items="${listOfParamValue}">
     <option><c:out value="${temp}" /></option>
    </c:forEach>
   </select>
  </c:forEach>
 </c:if>`

Answer (score 0):

user3218114 was correct.Issue was that I was using "param".param is used to access request parameter.

Comment: Is it your answer or comment?